# Weird 2D Jump Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a really weird problem that I couldn't figure out how to fix for days. I have 2 buttons on the screen. One is for jumping and the other is for attacking.

When I press on jump button, nothing happens until I press attack afterwards. When I press attack right after pressing the jump button, player attacks and jumps at the same time.

If I don't press attack after jump, nothing happens. This problem occurs only when the animator component on the gameobject is active. When it's deactivated, player doesn't jump at all.

These are the methods:

```
 public void Jump()
{

  if(isGrounded && canJump)
    {
      anim.SetTrigger("jump");
      p.velocity = new Vector2(0,jumpHeight);
      canJump = false;
    }                  
}

   public void Attack()
{
    if(canAttack())
    { 
         anim.SetTrigger("attack");
    }
}
```

And this is how Animator component looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xT9N.jpg

Here is how `canMove`,`canAttack`, and `canRun` are calculated:

```
//This defines if the character has the ability to move while attacking
bool canMove()
{
    if (agile == false)
    {
        if(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (agile)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
//Game is an endless runner so, when the game starts and character isn't dead, character keeps running.
bool canRun()
{
    if(m.gameStarted && ph.isDead == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool canAttack()
{

    if(!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack") && isGrounded && canJump)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you uncheck **Apply Root Motion**?

Comment: Player stays at idle, and doesn't move/attack at all.

Comment: Where do you set the bools canAttack/Jump and isGrounded?

Comment: Here they are: https://pastebin.com/mUvRVNEg

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53084968/edit) your question and include where you **set** `canJump` and `isGrounded`. It's not enough to know how `canJump` is calculated.

Comment: Also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53084968/edit) your question and include a screenshot or diagram of your animation state machine and the animation transitions from `idle` (or whatever) to your jumping state. Of most interest are the `conditions` of that transition.